# Card with 10 tickets. What is it called?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for the English word to describe a card which can be sold to a customer which contains several tickets. For instance, in a fitness center you can buy a card which allows you to participate in classes 10 times.

The closest thing I have is "punch card", but not having English as my main language, I'm not sure if that is correct.

Comment: Carnet?  a book of tickets, travel coupons, etc

Comment: I think 'book' would be nearest. A set of 10 raffle tickets is called a book.

Comment: If they're distinct, a book of tickets. If it's a card that can be marked or hole punched, a punch card.

Comment: I don't think there is an agreed upon term for them where I'm at: A local ski resort sells "ten-time" passes. Local transit sells a "book of 10." And the rock climbing gym sells "10 visit" passes.

Comment: I'm not clear on what the physical transaction is that is taking place here, and that tends to determine the name. If there are physical tickets torn out, it is a book of tickets. If it is a card which is scanned and not physically altered, it is a "pass". If it is a card which is punched or otherwise physically marked, it is, as OP and @SrJoven mentioned, a "punch card".

Comment: Ticket Book is what I hear it referred to.

Comment: Is there any localization here?  In the US, "punch card" sounds right to me.

Comment: Understand that public transportation (the classical user of such devices) in the US is quite diverse and no-standardized, and the terms used in one city might be totally "foreign" in another city 500 miles away.  But "punch card" or "10-visit pass" or some such would be understood by most.

Comment: Like most usage questions, this can't be answered properly without knowing where you intend to use the word.

Comment: @Joe OP's profile says he's Swedish, so I would expect a European context.

Comment: @Mynamite At that size, "booklet" would be more appropriate.

Comment: This may be the wrong question to ask, because many people at present are far more familiar with loyalty cards and access cards than carnet tickets.  A loyalty card is not a carnet ticket, but because of that familiarity, some term like "<name of business> card" or something like "10 visit pass" may be better understood.

Comment: @200_success That might sound more sensible given its size, but I've never heard it called that. I think it's connected to 'bookmaking' in the betting sense.

Comment: Are you actually asking about collections of specifically *ten* tickets, or would any other number of tickets do as well? After all, *ten* seems to be just an arbitrary number, and the actual number of tickets that can be bought as a set at a somewhat reduced price would vary from company to company.

Comment: why has nobody mentioned "multipass"? h/t Leeloo.

Answer (score 22):

The French word *carnet* is used in English public transport networks for a ticket (or a book of tickets) which can be used on more than one journey.

> Pronunciation: /ˈkɑːneɪ/
>
> 1. A book of tickets for use on public transport in some countries.
>
> [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/carnet)

> ### Carnet tickets
>
> If you travel regularly to and from London but not often enough to buy a Season ticket, the Carnet ticket booklet could save you time and money.
>
> You can buy a Carnet booklet of either five or 10 single journey tickets and you’ll save 10%. Your Carnet tickets will need to be used within three months and only from selected stations. Don’t forget that Carnet tickets are one-way, so you’ll need a separate book of Carnet tickets for your return journeys.
>
> There are two types of Carnet tickets to choose from:
>
> - Anytime tickets - unrestricted travel
> - Off-Peak tickets - choose this if you:
>
>   - Arrive in London after 10:00 Monday to Friday
>   - Leave London after 09:30 Monday to Friday
>   - Travel before 16:30 and after 19:01 Monday to Friday
>   - Travel on public holidays
>
> Please note that Carnet booklets are only available as Standard Class fares.
>
> [Thameslink Railway](http://www.thameslinkrailway.com/tickets-and-fares/carnet/)

Comment: *Carnet* is only used in the U.K.; I have never seen it in the U.S. On the commuter rail systems I have used, these are called *"ten-trip"* or *"ten-ride"* tickets, exhibiting a sad lack of vocabulary in the U.S.

Comment: I don't think it's universally understood in the UK either: only in areas where the local transport authority has used it.

Comment: At least ten-ride ticket is clearly understood by all English-speaking people @PeterShor! :-)  If you asked my for my "carnet" on a train, I might say I only carry it on days when I have band rehearsal. lol!

Comment: @KristinaLopez - Ticket Inspectors would usually ask for tickets, not for carnets. Carnet is just a way to call a group of tickets when you buy them. But as noted it is probably a European usage...France and Italy use 'carnet' in that sense.

Comment: Darn...there goes my carnet/cornet joke @Josh61!  But at least I learned something new today! :-)

Comment: I've never heard of "carnet".

Comment: Multiple carnets = a carnetcopia.

Comment: A carnet to me implies something different. It is most commonly a booklet, rather than a single pass, and it nearly always has some kind of restriction (like your quote here: must be used within three months, only from certain stations, only one-way). The punch cards the asker is looking for here are a different kettle of fish: they're single cardboard cards that can be punched ten times, anywhere within the zones they're valid for, and allow you unlimited travel within a given set of zones and a given time frame.

Comment: Not sure exactly how the Swedish ones generally look, but [here’s one from neighbouring Denmark](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Klippekort02.JPG) (with eight punches/trips already used and two left).

Comment: Can I really use carnet for gym classes (which is what I want to use the word for, not for transportation tickets)? Is it UK only?

Answer (score 9):

If it's a solitary card from which 10 uses is used and somehow marred/marked, then calling it a punch card in the USA is easily understood, even if physical "punches" aren't used.

A good alternative could be called a Voucher Card. I can't speak for English usage for slang/jargon outside the USA though.

Comment: I don't think "punch card" would be understood to mean that in the UK.

Comment: I was afraid of that, thus the caveat :-/ Thank you for the clarification, David Richerby.

Answer (score 7):

Ticket Booklet? Not entirely sure if this is what you are looking for, as this is not a single card, but a small book of many tickets. Thought I'd suggest it though.

Answer (score 6):

In Italy a group of ten separate bus tickets are called *carnet*, but they have translated the expression as **10-trips book of tickets**.

It's not a single word but it's perfectly comprehensible, and I imagine that whoever translated the French term knew that many non UK English speaking people would be unfamiliar with the expression, *carnet*.

[image][image]

You could shorten it to **multi-trip** or **ten-trip tickets**, I think this solution is more elegant and  self explanatory at the same time.

If a person wishes to purchase a limited subscription to a gym (in my experience subscriptions are monthly or annual, but maybe that's only true in Italy) then I'd suggest

- **multi-gym session (entry)**
  or
- **ten gym sessions (pass)**

Answer (score 4):

In our country it is called a 'subscription card'. It may vary, either for 8 classes or 12. But still it is a subscription.
To say about a gym - probably '**gym membership**' card

About public transport - **travel card** or **pass**.

Comment: I'm from Belarus.

Comment: We have that name in Russian language but in English it's almost the same meaning

Comment: I don't think that term would be understood in the UK.

Comment: Well, yeah, probably in dedication to gym - it may be gym membership card. As for public transport - we use travel card or pass.

Comment: Or you could always say "Multipass," preferably pronounced "mooltee pass."

Comment: _Membership card_ and _travel pass_ are both existing terms that refer to something quite different from what is being asked here. If you have a card/pass that allows you unlimited usage within a given period (usually a month), that's a membership card or travel pass.

Answer (score 3):

The kind of card with a number of locations on it to punch holes or stamp with ink is the earliest form of a customer loyalty card. Generally called a punch card or a stamp card and usually result in getting a gift when all of the holes are punched/stamped (e.g.: buy 10 and get one free).

Answer (score 2):

For a fitness center, I'd use **"10-visit pass."**

Answer (score 1):

Ten-ride Ticket (or Ten-rides Ticket, I've seen both) is the phrase various public transport organizations in the Netherlands use in English information for tourists.

Not sure if that is officially English, but at least it is pretty clear what it means.

Carnet is used in France and Italy and also by English public transport, but I have never heard it used as a common term by native speakers (I have lived in the UK for a while).

I just asked an American colleague what she would call it and she, after a lot of thought came up with "Gee, I don't know... Maybe a ticket-book or something like that ?"
She actually preferred the Dutch "Ten-ride Ticket" term as a better name, when I mentioned that to her.

Answer (score 1):

The term *multi-ride* is used by numerous transit authorities in the US to describe passes that allow either a set number of trips or unlimited trips within a set period of time. The term is usually followed by a term such as *car, pass* or *ticket*.

A web search of *multi-ride* provides examples, such as [this one](http://mta.maryland.gov/sites/default/files/ConversionTable.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on context it may be preferable to simply use the local word for such tickets. If you use an existing English word you risk implying some assumptions that are not necessarily true for this specific ticket system.

If you happen to be the issuer of such tickets you have some freedom in choosing what translation you want to use for your specific ticket system. It is more of a marketing decision than a question about what is correct.

---

Fore reference, here is a Danish *klippekort*:

[image]

It could be called a *punch card* or a *rebate card*. When used in context most Danes would probably understand either of those terms. *10-trip rebate card* would not need as much context to be understood. But the term is both a bit long for common reference, and  technically imprecise, as the card may also be used for fewer longer trips.

The seemingly fitting description *travel card* would not be acceptable in Denmark as that refers to a different ticketing system. You can't safeguard against such translation mistakes without knowing the local context.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single (non-British) English word to describe '*a*' **card which can be sold to a customer which contains *several* tickets**. '*A*' card cannot contain multiple tangible objects.

- You can have a *single* punchable\mark-able\tab-removable\magnetic-swipable **card**;
- Or you can have (containing multiple, individual card stocks) a **ticket book**, also sometimes known as season tickets; if they are bound. If they are not bound, they're just a stack of tickets.

I'd suggest against using the word, *carnet*, which is used "in [only] some [areas of English speaking] countries".

Answer (score -3):

I would call it a Season Ticket.

Comment: Misunderstanding, I think: a season ticket allows as many journeys as you want within the specified period, what is sought is something that allows you to make exactly ten trips, with no (or not much) time restriction. Myself I call it a *carnet* in italics, because I first encountered it when the Paris Metro sold literally ten cardboard tickets in a paper wrapper for the price of nine(?). Ah, the old days.

Comment: No. That is one meaning of season ticket. This is another. I have a booklet from the Halifax Thespians with a tear-off voucher for each play in their season: I do not have a ready word for this, but if pressed, I would call it a season ticket.

Comment: Wow. Holding season tickets to the Astros is pretty bad. Holding season tickets to the Santa Clara VTA would be absolutely unbearable.

Comment: I would have to say that if you chose to call your Halifax booklet a "season ticket", then you would be mis-using the term; I agree with @TimLymington that a season ticket is a single item that allows you unlimited entry within a defined period.

Comment: @Hellion - It's context dependent. If I get a season pass at my local skating rink, I can skate for free anytime there's public skating at the rink. If I get season tickets for a local theater company, though, I get one seat at each production for that season, sometimes assigned to a particular night (e.g., I might have a ticket for the Friday night production, but not the Saturday night production or the Sunday matinee).

Comment: @ColinFine If your season ticket lets you go to every performance, then that's the same as being able to go as often as you like, because there aren't any performances you can miss. A season pass to an amusement park wouldn't let you in at night, just when they're open. If you had a book that let you attend 9 out of 10 of the performances, that would not be a season pass, because there are performances during the season for which you don't have a pass.

Comment: @Helion, I suggest you google 'Theatre "season ticket"' or 'Orchestra "season ticket"' and see how many other organisations "mis-use" the phrase in a similar way to how I "mis-use" it. I rather take exception to being down-voted for saying how I use a word, particularly when I can show that I am not alone!